# What is this landing/wrap-around feature on porch steps called.

Tags: concrete, masonry, stone, porch, steps

What is this style or feature called? If it has a name...!

[image]

Comment: dressed stone steps and landing with side walls.

Comment: @ojait awesome! I guess it was a pretty simple question for someone who knows the answer!

Comment: errm... to be honest that was what I  see in your photo (more of a description, actually).  It my have an architectural title or label that someone may chime in with shortly.

Comment: Seems unfinished.  I would expect it to have handrails or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dressed stone steps and landing with side walls.